# How to integrate angular 2 into Spring MVC project built using Maven

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc

I want to implement an angular 2 based app with a backend in Spring MVC. I was able to implement a basic web app using maven in eclipse on the Spring MVC. I know how the basic jsp system works. I now need to know how to integrate angular 2 into the project. I have a basic idea of angular 2 but am having some problems regarding how to deal with its dependencies in the spring mvc. Could you give me some directions?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have edited the question. Is it fine now?

Comment: Almost. Now you have to show some effort. We here **usually** don't help people that don't show any effort. SO is not a free code service.

Comment: Anyways, I got what I was looking for on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35704973/how-to-configure-angular2-application-using-typescript-with-maven/37398298#37398298

Comment: https://github.com/Kiran-N/springboot-and-angular2